# FB:comments getting height getting "unhealthily" cut

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

For some reason this simple FB coments  is getting cut at like 100px height, no mater if I define the height or not.

I have spent something like 2 hours trying to figure this out so far :s

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=111111111111";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.FOO.org/">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this style in your header.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .fb_ltr { min-height:100%; } 
</style>
```